# Framework independently resource loading

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

at the moment I'm coding a c++ GUI application. The main intent in this project is to achieve a program, that works on various platforms. My approach is to use the MVP-architecture (passive View) to encapsulate the used GUI-Framework, so that I can easily write different GUIs using different frameworks for various platforms.

My main issue is how to get resources (e.g. icons for menu/toolbar) in the program in a GUI-Framework independently way. For Qt there is the .qrc file, for .Net the .rc file. But i don't want to code the whole resources infrastructure for each GUI in a different way. Maybe some GUI-experienced developer knows a way to load resources in a c++ project so that they can be used in every GUI.

thanks

Comment: The resources depend on the framework, they are not depend on the c++ language. So, you will always have to create a new resource file for each framework that provide resource file. You can check out for tools that convert resource file to other framework resource. But, I couldn't find one for you.